# Avoid AndroidX Jetifier log spam

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, android-jetifier

I recently migrated my app to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview) and thus use the Jetifier tool (currently the version bundled with Android Gradle plugin version `3.3.0-alpha10`):

```
# gradle.properties
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

It works fine, but adds *many* logs (for every library it transforms) like below throughout a build of my app and makes the logs hard to read.

It looks like this:

```
> Transform room-runtime.aar (androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01) with AarTransform
> Transform lifecycle-extensions.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01) with AarTransform
> Transform work-runtime.aar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha08) with AarTransform
```

Is there any way to disable/ignore/filter these logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Filtering out terminal/command line:**

To filter-out output in terminal/command line use grep or some equivalent. On unix system it would go something like this:

```
./gradlew build | grep -vE 'Transform'
```

Windows grep's equivalent is findstr, so the whole command would look like this:

```
./gradlew build | findstr /V "Transform"
```

**Filtering out logcat:**

If you have too any logs in the logcat, one possible solution is to filter-out all Jetifier's logs using the [Android Studio log filters](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat). You can do advanced filtering by clicking on the dropdown at the top right corner of Logcat menu and choosing **Edit Filter Configuration** and specifying what to filter on.

[image]

In your case the filter should look something like this. This configuration will filter-out all messages with 'Transform' tag *(I'm not sure whether Transform is a tag or just a part of a message)*. 
[image]

Most likely you will want to create a more advanced configuration so that only logs from your package get to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I meant. I was talking about the Gradle Build logs. For example after calling `./gradlew build` from the command line.

Comment: Oh, I see. So maybe if you are using unix system, you could use grep? Something like this should work: ./gradlew build | grep -vE 'Transform'

Comment: And for Windows, grep's equivalent is something like this: findstr /V "Transform"

Comment: Didn't event think about such approach, thanks that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: This runs the risk of hiding completely unrelated logging